# UnknownHostException at the android emulator

Tags: android, emulation, hosts-file, unknown-host

I've got an **UnknownHostException** in my android application when I want to get to my web service.

I inserted an `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` at my AndroidManifest.xml.

If I go to my link of webservice via browser it's going fine.

I typed the domain name and IP at the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file.

But if I run application via emulator I got an **UnknownHostException**. As I understand, emulator should use my system files to connect with the server...But, practically it doesn't..Help please with this issue.

Comment: have you tired 10.0.2.2 as host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved using such domains as

```
CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http//192.168.1.2/path");
```

Everything works fine with it. I can't edit hosts file in android file system even with root rights. So if you have similar problem - good solution is to use IP addresses, not domains.

Thanks to [Haresh Chaudhary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1155805/haresh-chaudhary)

Comment: If you are using a virtual host, a domain name is required so an IP won't work...

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I encountered this problem when I had started the emulator while I was logged on to a VPN.  Logging off the VPN had no effect until I quit the emulator and restarted.  It is easy to test if your emulator is not resolving names correctly - just go to the **emulator** browser and type in a website hostname (anything but Google's).

Comment: When this happens to me I have to exit the emulator and relaunch it

Comment: Restarting Android from within the emulator doesn't seem to do it. I had to select "Cold Boot Now" from the device manager in Android Studio. Otherwise it was spot on, my VPN somehow disabled the emulator's Internet access.

Answer (score 0):

**A very nice tutorial for connecting with the webservice is [here](http://wowjava.wordpress.com/2011/01/16/login-application-for-android/)**

**You will come through this line in this tutorial..**

```
CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http//192.168.1.2/path");
```

here ***path*** means path of your ***file placed*** in `htdocs`.